# Best way to make a token after authentication web api

Tags: web-services, api, authentication, token

I have made a very small web api and I already enabled SSL on my server. My web api gives important data that I don't want anyone to see, only authenticated users. My question is what's the best approach to do this?. I have readed the method used by AWS and also the OAuth 2 legged but I don't know if these are the best solution.

Also I want to authenticate users using this web api to allow access to others system that I develope in the future but I don't know if once that the user is authenticated I need to create a token or something that proves that this user is valid

Thanks